# init.d script launches manually but not via services command or on startup

Tags: subversion, init.d

I have a subversion init.d script that is able to be launched manually if I launch it

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/subversion start
```

I get this response:

```
$ Starting Subversion Daemon (svnserve):                     [  OK  ]
```

However if I add the script via

```
$ sudo /sbin/chkconfig --add subversion
```

And then run:

```
$ /sbin/service subversion start
```

I get this response:

```
$ Starting Subversion Daemon (svnserve): /etc/init.d/subversion: Usage: daemon [+/-nicelevel] {program}
```

Has anyone seen this before? Permissions are +x on the script. init.d script below:

/etc/init.d/subversion:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    #
    #   /etc/init.d/subversion
    #
    # Starts the Subversion Daemon
    #
    # chkconfig: 2345 90 10
    # description: Subversion Daemon


    # copied from http://www.svnforum.org/threads/31170-init.d-script-for-fedora-redhat


    # processname: svnserve

    source /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions

    [ -x /usr/bin/svnserve ] || exit 1

    ### Default variables
    SYSCONFIG="/etc/sysconfig/subversion"

    ### Read configuration
    [ -r "$SYSCONFIG" ] && source "$SYSCONFIG"

    RETVAL=0
    prog="svnserve"
    desc="Subversion Daemon"

    start() {
        echo -n $"Starting $desc ($prog): "
            daemon --user $USER $prog -d $OPTIONS
            RETVAL=$?
            [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ] && touch /var/lock/subsys/$prog
            echo
    }

    stop() {
            echo -n $"Shutting down $desc ($prog): "
            killproc $prog
            RETVAL=$?
            [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ] && success || failure
            echo
        [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ] && rm -f /var/lock/subsys/$prog
            return $RETVAL
    }


    case "$1" in
      start)
            start
        ;;
      stop)
            stop
        ;;
      restart)
        stop
        start
        RETVAL=$?
            ;;
      condrestart)
        [ -e /var/lock/subsys/$prog ] && restart
            RETVAL=$?
            ;;
      *)
            echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|condrestart}"
            RETVAL=1
    esac

    exit $RETVAL
```

/etc/sysconfig/subversion:

```
 OPTIONS="-r /data/repository/"
```

Comment: What init system are you using? Upstart? `systemd`?

Comment: It's Red Hat 5.10, so SysV, sorry should've mentioned that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue with the daemon command that you are using in the init script.
The `$USER` variable is not being set so when passing the argument to the daemon function:

```
        --user)
               user=$2
               shift 2
               ;;
```

The `svnserve` argument is being used for `user=$2` and therefore leaving `-d` to be parsed by the function:

```
        *)     echo $"$0: Usage: daemon [+/-nicelevel] {program}"
               return 1;;
```

So either hard code the `USER` variable in the script or remove the `--user $USER` from the `daemon` argument.

Also you should hard code the path for the `$prog` variable:

```
prog=/usr/bin/svnserve
```

Comment: Great explanation and answer. Much appreciated!